# List of dictionary within dictionary using for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop

I am creating a random color for xlsxwriter in python

```
import random
point = []
dict1 = {}
for row_count in range(3):

    fill = {
    "color": '#' + ''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for x in range(6)]),
}
    dict1['fill'] = fill
    print fill
    point.append(dict1)
print point
```

**Expected output**

```
[{'fill': {'color': '#8C4372'}}, {'fill': {'color': '#5EF546'}}, {'fill': {'color': '#386CF4'}}]
```

**Actual Output**

```
{'color': '#8C4372'}
{'color': '#5EF546'}
{'color': '#386CF4'}
[{'fill': {'color': '#386CF4'}}, {'fill': {'color': '#386CF4'}}, {'fill': {'color': '#386CF4'}}]
```

How to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks like the expected output to my eyes... What is the problem ?

Comment: If you remove the ` print fill`, you will have the expected output

Comment: move `dict1 = {}` into the for loop

Comment: FWIW, I'd probably do something like `from random import randrange;[{'fill':{'color':'#%06X'%randrange(0x1000000)}}for _ in'...']` but that's just me. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may achieve the same using a *list comprehension* expression as:

```
[{'file': {'color': ''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for x in range(6)])}} for row_count in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 6):

You use the same dictionary dict1 for all fill objects, create new one each time you add it to points:

```
import random
point = []
for row_count in range(3):
    fill = {
        "color": '#' + ''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for x in range(6)]),
    }
    point.append({"fill": fill})
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're re-using `dict1` and re-assigning the "fill" key.  Since it's shared between all the entries, all the entries will get the new value.  Do this instead:

```
import random

def random_color():
    return '#' + ''.join(random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for x in range(6))

rows = []
for _ in range(3):
    fill = {"color": random_color()}
    rows.append({"fill": fill})

print rows
```

Or use a list comprehension instead:

```
rows = [{'fill': {'color': random_color()}} for _ in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the range of colours is from 0x000000 to 0xFFFFFF you could generate a random colour using `randint()`:

```
from random import randint

'#%6X' % randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)
```